# How to get result of 2 combined arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, $m and $w:

```
$m = Array(
 [0] => a
 [1] => b
 [2] => c
);

$w = Array(
 [0] => 1
 [1] => 2
 [2] => 3
);
```

How may I combime those 2 arrays to get result like this:

```
$arrFields = Array(
     Array( 
       "VALUE" => a,
       "DESCRIPTION" => 1 
     ), 
     Array( 
       "VALUE" => b, 
       "DESCRIPTION" => 2  
     ),
     Array( 
       "VALUE" => c, 
       "DESCRIPTION" => 3 
     )
);
```

Help me to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: Please, show your attempts.

Comment: by usnig php function get $arrFields array (print_r($arrFields)).

Comment: I hope you know `print_r()` does not combine arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do the thrick: combine both arrays with the same keys.
It also checks if the second array has the same key, otherwise it'll make the description empty.

```
$arrFields = array();
foreach ($m as $k => $v) {
    $arrFields[] = array(
        'VALUE' => $v,
        'DESCRIPTION' => (isset($w[$k]) && !empty($w[$k]) ? $w[$k] : '')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

(Here I just go through each element of `$m` with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and return the array with the values from `$m` and `$w`)

```
<?php

    $m = array("a", "b", "c");
    $w = array(1, 2, 3);

    $arrFields = array_map(function($v)use($w, $m){
        return array("VALUE" => $v, "DESCRIPTION" => $w[array_search($v, $m)]);
    }, $m);

    print_r($arrFields);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [VALUE] => a
            [DESCRIPTION] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [VALUE] => b
            [DESCRIPTION] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [VALUE] => c
            [DESCRIPTION] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: @sectus But only a little bit :D (lol forgot that you can use multiple arrays with array map)

Answer (score 2):

More convenient way of using [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) function

```
$return = array_map(function($m_item, $w_item){
    return array("VALUE" => $m_item, "DESCRIPTION" => $w_item);
    }, $m, $w);
print_r($return);
```